# How to use colabctl to run colab notebooks automatically?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I need to run a colab notebook everyday so i've seen I can do this automatically with [colabctl](https://github.com/TensorTom/colabctl), but i've had some truble unterstanding how to do so.

What i've done: change keyboard shortcuts, download the colabctl.py file and replace "colab_urls = file_to_list('notebooks.csv')" with colab_urls = 'https://colab.research.google.com/drive/{my_notebook}'.

But when i run the file i get an error in this line:

```
fork = sys.argv[1]
```

IndexError: list index out of range

An example of how to use colabctl would be very useful

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you forgot to insert parameters. If you're running the script from the terminal you should:

```
python colabctl.py <end-string> <sleep-seconds>
```

For example:

```
python colabctl.py forkinme 1800
```

In case you're using PyCharm, go to Edit configurations, and add to parameters: forkinme 1800